# Kubernetes deleted pod IP address is refere by rabbitmq which is still accepting messages

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-networking

I am running RabbitMQ on kubernetes as service, and I have multiple microservices which get register and consumes message from rabbitmq.

Services are running in Multi Node cluster

I have install **RabbitMQ using Bitnami helm chart 8.6.1** with single replica

I have 2 replicas for each service (Consumers) so there must be atmost 2 consumer for that event on rabbitmq.

After deploying new container (consumer) on K8s old container (Consumer) which already got terminated still visible on RabbitMQ connection and that cosumer is still accepting messages, and because of that old pod code gets executed (That old container was registered at 2nd April 2021).

1. I have verified that new deployment has all updated images with new hash.
2. I have checked all IP addess on K8S pod but that unwated IP is not visible.

Does anyone knows how can I trace that old pod IP on k8s, because that pod is no longer visible in k8s get pods.

Thanks

Comment: Is it single node or multi-node cluster?

Comment: Its multi node cluster

Comment: I suspect that pod is terminated but container is still running. You can check that by docker ps.

Comment: @dotnetstep those are in k8s, so where should I run that command ?

Comment: Basically K8s is just orchestrator and behind the scene it uses or Docker or similar to create container. so for each node if you execute docker ps you will get to know exact container running on that machine.

Comment: Could you please tell how you perform this `After deploying new container (consumer) on K8s old container (Consumer)` ?
Also please check `kubectl get events` and [scheduler logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/) if possible.